# T-SQL WHILE (SELECT ())

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do something that would take me less than 1 minute doing it in any language. I am trying to "sort of" iterate a table in a store procedure, but to my surprise it's not possible.

So I am trying to create a store procedure, just for testing/learning purposes, using the while ((SELECT)) approach in a way to update certain rows, from range 96811 to 96815 (the max(id) is something like 96830).

Ok, this is what I am trying:

```
while ((select min(id) from parser) <= 96815)
    begin
        update parser set tempID=id+1 where id<=96815
        if ((select max(tempID) from parser)>=96815)
            break
    end
```

Now, the problem is that the while() is not doing what I want, which is basically getting the first N rows up to id=96815. Then the UPDATE should work with that subset only.

At this point, just the UPDATE line by itself would do the trick and work enough.

So is there a way to do what I want in a sort of what you would do through any language, getting a recordset, iterating it, updating what you need and exiting?

I took this approach from something posted in MSDN:

```
WHILE ((SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM dbo.DimProduct) < $300)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DimProduct
                    SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2;
        IF ((SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM dbo.DimProduct) > $500)
    BREAK;
END
```

But looks like in their example it won't either work.

Comment: Thanks for the editting Dale, this is my first question ever on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you're trying to be fast, then "iterate" is probably the opposite of what you want to do. And by "any language" are you referring to SQL languages or other programmatic languages?

Comment: Aside from the answer Tyler has provided and should be fine, you will need to change your mindset on looping unless you explicitly NEED to within a stored procedure.  I understand you wanting to learn writing stored procedures, but most stuff within SQL is "set" oriented... BTW, welcome to S/O

Comment: any reason why you need the while loop? sql does that for you with the right constraints

Comment: Yes, again, a simple UPDATE statement with a BETWEEN or > and < would do what I want. But I am trying to understand this WHILE (SELECT()) approach posted by MSDN guys. See the MSDN code they provide. Aren't they trying to update prices in a certain range?

Comment: @DiegoSendra I wouldn't use MSDN (even though it's their product) as much more than a language reference. Again, what works well on their limited test bench may not work in real-world situations. The important thing to learn from their example is that, according to actual use cases of outside people, their way is wrong. And one of the main aspects of learning involves things you learn first. So if you learn a bad habit early, it will stick with you a lot longer than it should. `while` loops definitely fall into the realm of Bad Habits. Hit up http://www.sqlservercentral.com/.

Comment: Also http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: @DiegoSendra No, they aren't trying to update prices in a certain range. They are doubling the prices until the average price exceeds $300. There is a *very specific* reason they're using a `WHILE`, and that's because *it is not known how many times, if any, that the loop body will be required to run*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
update parser set tempID=id+1
   where id in (select id from table where condition...)
```

Comment: Be careful with `IN`. It's essentially `WHERE id = x OR id = y OR id = z OR ....`.

Comment: @DiegoSendra See my comment above. They are doubling the list price of each item until the average list price is at least $300. The only reason they are using a `WHILE` is because it is not known beforehand how many times this process needs to be repeated in order to achieve the desired goal.

Comment: Yes, I got it... and thanks. That example confussed me, to be honest.

Comment: I think the two approaches are good, @Gauravsa and a simple UPDATE within a range. What I've learned is what I was thinking about the MSDN example, when I posted the question is not what in fact it was doing, and not the way to do what I wanted. I will be avoiding while () approaches, at least for iterating/updating . The problem is I was thinking in terms of a regular language, not in T-SQL terms. Thanks you two for your help

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you first foray into SQL, it's best not to relate it to other common non-RDBMS languages.  It's entirely different, such to the extent that if you ever find yourself iterating in SQL (using something like `WHILE` or `CURSOR`), it's almost always a red flag.

> update certain rows, from range 96811 to 96815

All you need is...

```
UPDATE MyTable              -- Update your table
SET MyValue = MyValue + 1   -- Increase MyValue by 1
WHERE Id >= 96811           -- Wherever the ID is between 96811 and 96815
AND Id <= 96815
```

Comment: Of course, that's obvious. But look at the sample provided by MSDN about updating the price field.

Comment: @DiegoSendra Just FYI, what works very well on a few rows will likely make you want to punch things when you hit a few hundred thousand or million rows. I would honestly say there are probably very few actual cases in any flavor of SQL where a `WHILE` loop is beneficial.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. The problem is I am about to get hired as a DBA. And with over 20 years developing experience, I couldn't hate T-SQL, store procedures and functions more. I think the logic should be all the way made through CODE, not through the retarded way T-SQL handle it's logic....

Comment: many times, because of frequenct changeds in UI and lack of logical tier, many people prefer to code their logic in sql.. this allows them to change their UI and keep the logic intact..

Comment: yes, whatever... I am hating T-SQL. Give me C# all the time, and I can iterate a recordset with .read()

Comment: [**“Never do in code what SQL can do well."**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171024/never-do-in-code-what-you-can-get-the-sql-server-to-do-well-for-you-is-this/171033)

Comment: `"And with over 20 years developing experience, I couldn't hate T-SQL, store procedures and functions more. I think the logic should be all the way made through CODE, not through the retarded way T-SQL handle it's logic."` <<< Even as a developer, this is an idea that you should change. Essentially, your data is a screw. C# is a hammer. SQL is a screwdriver. Yes, C# will work. But it's not the right tool. And the more you work with the database itself, the more you will realize that you were really working much harder in C# than you needed to be doing.

Comment: And you'll see that DBAs don't yell at developers just cause they like it.

Comment: It is not my place to offer any sort of career advice, but hating SQL (**the** standard language for relational database management systems) and taking a job as a DBA is like hating car engines and taking a job as a mechanic.

Comment: Well, the problem is hate frameworks as well  :) And in .net you have plenty of them, from Entity to angular, to react, to a few dozen coming up every year. In fact, I am a game developer and even that way, I am coding it all in c# and monogame, not using Unity. But I need the money and I need to employ myself until I have the game ready to make me some money.

Comment: You should read some of the answers on the question I linked above. By not using SQL, you're nullifying all the benefits of using a relational database in the first place - key integrity, select and filter efficiency, simplified aggregation - just to name a few.